# How to set language abbreviation in url for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing multilanguage site. I am facing issue with language abbreviation in url. Fo default language i set english language i can saw abbreviation en in url. But when i change my language to french it doesn't show me fr abbriavation in url.I developed this functionality from this url
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier 
Can anyone please solve me this issue ? I tried lot but didn't got success.

Comment: to make it visible in  URL just set $config['lang_ignore'] = TRUE; to FALSE. if it is true it uses cookie to save active language try it will work

Answer (score 0):

Please Check the following two things with respect to your question
(i) Make `$config['lang_ignore'] = FALSE` which seems to be TRUE as the content you are referring has TRUE.
(ii) Please check your `$config['lang_uri_abbr']` which has key value pair with respect to french language `"fr" => "french"` 
Hope it will help you.Looking forward for further comments.
Thanks,